# Printing the output of command to text area/text panel - JSch

Tags: java, jsch

The program is part of JSch which previously use to reads the output content and then print it to console, But I have made UI which has textPanel and I want to write the extracted content to the text area. But I am getting Null pointer exception. There is something wrong the way I am calling the textPanel.

JumpHosts - http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html (For Full Program)

```
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    //System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                    textPanel.appendText(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    //System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    textPanel.appendText(new String("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus()));
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    System.out.println(ee);
                }
            }`
```

Text Panel Code here :

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel {

private JTextArea textArea;

public TextPanel(){

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    textArea = new JTextArea();

    add(new JScrollPane(textArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void appendText(String tmp){

    textArea.append(tmp);

}
```

Text Panel is Initialized in MainFrame class :

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

private TextPanel textPanel;
private Toolbars toolbar;
private FormPanel formPanel;;

public MainFrame() {

    super("ABC");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

    textPanel = new TextPanel();
    toolbar = new Toolbars();
    formPanel = new FormPanel();

    toolbar.setStringListener(new StringListeners() {
        public void textEmitter(String text) {
            textPanel.appendText(text);
        }
    });

    formPanel.setFormListener(new FormListener(){
        public void formEventOccured(FormEvent e){
            String name = e.getName();
            String occupation = e.getOccupation();

            textPanel.appendText(name + " : " + occupation + "\n");

        }       
    });

    add(textPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(toolbar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(formPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    setSize(600, 500);

}
```

Comment: Where did you initialize textPanel?

Comment: How would you help someome that asked you *"I have a program I won't show you the code, that throws a NPE at some point while running in some unspecified condition"*?

Comment: @Raffaele hope this helps